# Google Sheets Macro comparing values in range returns incorrect answer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to compare the values in a range with the values in a different array, but I keep getting incorrect answers.

My Macro

```
function getNPI(range) {
var match=["A","A","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","B","A","B","B","A","A","B","A","B","A","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A","A","A","B"];
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cellValues= sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
var count=0;
for (var i=0;i<cellValues.length;i++)
{
if(cellValues[i]==match[i])
  count++;
}
return "list length:"+cellValues.length+" items in list var:"+cellValues+" items in list func call:"+sheet.getRange(range).getValues()+" matching items:"+count;
}
```

The result in the spreadsheet:

```
list length:1 items in list var:A,B,A items in list func call:A,B,A matching items:0
```

The spreadsheet initial call

```
=getNPI("AE3:AG3")
```

The spreadsheet contains A in AE3, B in AF3, and A in AG3

If i change my code the use .getValue() instead it only returns the value in the first cell. Is there a way to make this work without having to iterate over each element in the array to record the value initially?

Answer (score 0):

When you use getValues(), you are returned a 2-dimensional Javascript array. In your example, it would be in the form:

`[["A", "B", "A"]]`

When you concatenate that array into your output string, it will give you the output you mentioned; however, cellValues is in fact an array that is one element long, containg an array that contains 3 elements. So if your referenced array will always be that form, then you should change the variable declaration to:

`var cellValues= sheet.getRange(range).getValues()[0];`

As an aside, is there any reason that you are not passing the range to the function directly?

```
function getNPI(range) {
  var match=["A","A","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","B","B","A","B","B","A","A","B","A","B","A","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A","A","A","B"];
  var cellValues = range[0];
  ...
```